# Learning embeddingment function for word embeddings

Tags: python, nlp

Given a sentence:

"I went to the mall" I translate this to french, "Je suis allé au centre commercial" and translate this sentence back to English again from french giving me the following: "I went to the shopping center"

So S_1 = "I went to the mall", S_2 = "I went to the shopping center". My task is to minimize the distance between these two sentences, yet I am unsure which method would prove to be the best. The overall task is to cluster n sentences into semantically equal clusters. Is there an NLP model architecture which takes a sentence as input and a sentence as target and minimizes the distance between these using the weights? Maybe representation learning? Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like unsupervised machine translation.

Comment: This is just a typical application of triplet loss?